# Plotting several variables in one ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I'm writing a paper in which I measure social inequality along different dimensions in different years. Right now I have a data frame with one row for each year ("Jahr") and 5 columns, one for each dimension. [my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVCnG.png)

Now I want to visualize the data in one single ggplot as a line chart. There should be one line for each dimension, so that I can see how each of the dimensions have changed over time.

But how do I do this? Since I have different variables that should be displayed as a line chart,I dont know what variable I should choose as y-axis

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Jahr, y= ?)
```

I  think I need to rearrange my data frame, so that I just have 3 columns as variables: Years, dimension and value. Then I could plot it like this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Jahre, y = value, group = dimension, color = dimension) +
geomline(...)
...
```

But how do I change my dataframe to such a format? I know this may sound stupid and easy to someone, but I'm a total noob at R.

Thanks in advance for every advice :)

Comment: Try `data %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(-Jahr, names_to = "dimension")`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to arrange the 5 columns into one in order to plot them as groups. With pivot_longer you can do this and all your variable values are arranged in a "value" column.

Just make sure to change the fake column names I added (x,y,z) with the correct ones.

```
library(dplyr)
new_data = pivot_longer(data, c('x','y','z'), 'col')
ggplot(new_data, aes(Jahr, value, group=col, color=col))+
  geom_line()
```